# Equivalent to SAS function repeat in PROC IML

Tags: string, sas, sas-iml

I want to define a string in a `PROC IML`, say "aaaaa" (five "a").
In a `DATA` step, I would use the `repeat()` function, which creates a string repeating substrings, as explained in [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245939.htm).

```
data _null_;
x=repeat('a',4);    /* string with five 'a' */
put x;
run;
```

However, in SAS/IML, the `repeat()` function is different : it creates a matrix repeating elements of another one (documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#langref_sect226.htm)).
So if I use this function, I will get a vector with five "a" elements.

```
proc iml;
x=repeat('a',5);    /* 5 'a' strings */
print x;
quit;
```

In that example, I could obviously not bother and go directly with :

```
x="aaaaa";
```

But what if I needed a larger string (say 100 "a" for example) ? I could also create it outside of the `PROC IML` and import it after but there must be a more clever way to address the problem, isn't there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to write a loop. Use the ROWCATC function to concatenate the elements across columns:

```
proc iml;
N = 10;
x = rowcatc(repeat("a", 1, N));  /* repeat 'a' N times */
print x (nleng(x))[L="Length"];
```

A slightly harder problem is to concatenate elements and insert some sort of delimiter beteen the elements (blanks, comas, etc). That problems is discussed in the article ["Convert a vector to a string."](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/07/27/vector-to-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

As IML works with matrices, that is what you normally would want.
To get columns instead of rows:

```
proc iml;
  x=repeat('a', 1, 5);   
  print x;
quit;

 x
a a a a a
```

You could convert the vector to string using a loop. But in that case it would make more sense to skip repeat and directly use a loop to produce a string:

```
proc iml;
  x="";
  do i = 1 to 5;
    x = x + 'a';
  end;
  print x;
quit;

 x
aaaaa
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I do need a single string and not a vector. I will be using it as default value when initializing a text vector. Your solution works well, but I was wondering if a function doing that existed in IML ?

Comment: I do not think so. All functions in IML are vector/matrix oriented. That is what IML is for. Everything else can be done in the BASE datastep.